# Передать в метод, нужный компонент вектора.

Tags: c#, unity3d

В коде много вот такого, причем когда обрабатывается одна ось - не обязательно должна обрабатыватся другая.

```
AxisX = ((currentTouchPos.x - startTouchPos.x) / workZoneInPixX);
AxisY = ((currentTouchPos.y - startTouchPos.y) / workZoneInPixY);
```

Отличаются только оси и чуть чуть название переменных.
Как передать это в метод, чтобы обрабатывать все похожие запросы этим?
Чтобы сократить и избежать дублирования кода
Вижу это как то примерно вот так

```
float FormatXY(x_or_y)
Axis = ((currentTouchPos.x_or_y - startTouchPos.x_or_y) / workZoneInPixX_or_Y);
return Axis;
```

Но понятно, что таким образом я просто передам значения x или y, а мне бы передать именно параметр *x компонент вектора* или *y компонент вектора*, и как то подставить это в методе.

Чтобы в результате, код

```
AxisX = FormatXY(X)
```

Был эквивалентен коду

```
AxisX = ((currentTouchPos.x - startTouchPos.x) / workZoneInPixX);
```

А код

```
AxisX = FormatXY(Y)
```

Был эквивалентен коду

```
AxisY = ((currentTouchPos.y - startTouchPos.y) / workZoneInPixY);
```

Comment: Можно, если задействовать рефлексию, но я не думаю что вы захотите увеличить время выполнения такой простой операции в разы, если не порядки.

Comment: @rdorn да зачем рефлексия? сергей вон предложил норм вариант. Остаётся только на вход функции дать char и сделать в нем два if в зависимости от char и всё. самый простой вариант. По сути Dmitrii сам всё себе расписал) просто чуть поправить его надо было)

Comment: дак я не против предложенного варианта =) но и так как вы хотели изначально тоже можно сделать, но не стоит из-за накладных расходов, разве что эксперимент с целью повышения образованности =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На беглый взгляд серебренной пули тут не найдешь. Думаю лучше написать две функции, типа `CurrentTouchX()` и `CurrentTouchY()` - куда запихать соответствующие выражения. Код сразу станет почище. Не думаю, что стоит городить что-то большее, ну может кто и придумает решение поинтереснее.

Answer (score 0):

Не судите строго первое что на ум пришло.

```
enum formatAx{
    "X",
    "Y"
}
float FormatXY(formatAx type){
    if (type == formatAx.x) {
        return = ((currentTouchPos.x - startTouchPos.x) / workZoneInPixX);
    }else {
        return = ((currentTouchPos.y - startTouchPos.y) / workZoneInPixY);
    }
}
```

Вызов будет таким:

AxisX = FormatXY(formatAx.X)

> Мог ошибиться, сам не проверял